# How to get property name of JSON Object in C#

Tags: c#, json

Here's a sample JSON data:

```
{"data_header":"[
    {   
        "id":"1",
        "name":"aa"
    },
    {   
        "id":"2",
        "name":"bb"
    }
]"}
```

In C# function, I do this to convert this data into my C# object:

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
JArray arr = (JArray)jsonObj["data_header"];
MyModel model = arr.ToObject<MyModel>();
```

Works fine. Now, how do I get this `"data_header"` value from `jsonObj` ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use Newtonsoft.json's JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(jsonData)

Comment: `string name = jsonObj.Properties().First().Name;`

Comment: @BrianRogers Perfect, Thanks :)

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder Thanks, but I've already tried that method which gave me an error before. :)

Answer (score 2):

Shanid,you mentioned you tried **@JayakrishnanGounder** solution and you got an error, is it possible your model may not be designed to handle the JSON data structure.

```
public class NameModel
{
   [JsonProperty("id")]
   public int id {get;set;}

   [JsonProperty("name")]
   public string name {get;set;}
}

public class ContainerModel
{
   [JsonProperty("data_header")]
   public List<NameModel> data_headeer
}
```

So now you should be able **@JayakrishnanGounder** method of deserialize using JSON.net.

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContainerModel>(json);
```

Comment: Yes, I did try this. But still, the error was there. Now it's working. Thanks anyways.